# A regular expression to check URL structure for jsfiddle links

Tags: javascript

How can I check if a given string is a valid URL address in the following format:

**jsfiddle.net/test/wLrk94mp**

- If a user prefixes the URL with **https://** or **http://** or **http://www** I'd like to remove it
- If a user adds a trailing slash to the end of the URL i.e. *jsfiddle.net/test/wLrk94mp/*, I'd like to remove it.

Here's my line of thinking so far (pseudocode):

1. Check if jsfiddle.net exists in the string with `indexOf('jsfiddle.net')`
2. Remove any URL prefixes
3. Remove any trailing slashes
4. Check if string can be split into 3 parts (jsfiddle, test, wLrk94mp)
5. If 1-4 are met then it is a good URL, if not then fail with error

Is there a way of approaching this with regex may as a one-liner, or should I stick with the linear step by step approach as above?

Comment: Use the `URL` class to parse out parts of the URL.  It will give you the protocol, host, query string, etc.  The `pathname` property can then be split on `/`, giving you easy access to each segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a super fancy Regex. Note that the look behind feature (`?<=`) is not supported in all browsers.

```js
const testCases = ['https://jsfiddle.net/test/wLrk94mp/', 'http://www.jsfiddle.net/test/wLrk94mp', '///jsfiddle.net/test/wLrk94mp/', 'www.jsfiddle.net/test/wLrk94mp/', '//www.jsfiddle.net/test/wLrk94mp', 'https://jsfiddle.net/test/wLrk94mp#hi/there', '/jsfiddle.net/test/wLrk94mp?hi=there#foo=bar', 'https://jsfiddle.net/test/wLrk94mp?hi=there'];

testCases.forEach((testCase) => {
  console.log(
    testCase.replace(/((\/+|https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(?=jsfiddle\.net\/test\/.{8})|(?<=jsfiddle\.net\/test\/.{8})\/*([?#].*)?)/gi, '')
  );
});
```

---

#### Let's go through the Regex

Here it is: `/((\/+|https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(?=jsfiddle\.net\/test\/.{8})|(?<=jsfiddle\.net\/test\/.{8})\/*([?#].*)?)/gi`

Let's break it down a bit though.

`/ ... /gi`

> First, we're going to make a Regex with the flags "g" and "i". "g" stands for **g**lobal, which means it will replace all matches, not just the first one. The "i" flag stands for case **i**nsensitive, which means we can pass in any kind of capitalisation. This is optional, if you are expecting lowercase text every time.

`(\/+|https?:\/\/)?`

> This checks for either `/`, `//`, `///`, `http://`, or `https://`. Brackets denotes a capture group, with the question mark indicating that certain characters or groups are optional. This is to replace any of the protocol bits in a URL.

`(www\.)?`

> This just replaces any `www.` in front of a URL with nothing. This too is an optional group.

`(?=jsfiddle\.net\/test\/.{8})`

> This is a positive lookahead - it checks that the string provided does actually contain the pattern "jsfiddle.net/test/8 characters`, without including it in the search result of a Regex.

`( ... | ... )`

> Simple or operator, to match this second group:

`(?<=jsfiddle\.net\/test\/.{8})`

> Same test pattern, but this time a negative lookahead. This allows us to check that the part BEFORE matches the jsfiddle pattern without including it in the search result.

`\/*`

> Checks for 0 or more trailing slashes.

`([?#].+*)?`

> Checks if there is a trailing hashtag or slash. If so, also check if there is 0 or more trailing characters after it. This entire group is optional once again.

---

#### Usage

Just use `str.replace(/((\/+|https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(?=jsfiddle\.net\/test\/.{8})|(?<=jsfiddle\.net\/test\/.{8})\/*([?#].*)?)/gi, '');` where `str` is any String.

---

#### Edit: Testing for a valid JSFiddle URL

The OP replied to another answer asking about validation. This can be done using the following JS:

```js
const testCases = ['https://jsfiddle.net/test/wLrk94mp#hello/there', '//tsfiddle.net/test/wLrk94mp//', 'http://www.jsfiddle.net/test/wLrk94mp//', 'not a link'];

testCases.forEach(testCase => {
  if (testCase.match(/((\/\/\/?|https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?jsfiddle\.net\/test\/.{8}?([?#].*)?)/gi))
    return console.log(true, testCase);
  console.log(false, testCase);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Great explanation. Quick question, how would I get it to `(?=jsfiddle\.net\/test\/.{8})` to match any text > 0 characters in length? `test` was just an example.

Comment: Replace it with `jsfiddle.net\/.+\/.+`. You could also turn it into a capture group and repeat that if you want to check for more than 2 paths deep.

Comment: Note to update both instances of that portion of the regex in both the look ahead and look behind

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [**URL API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_API) and its properties to get different segments of the URL.

```js
function validateJsfiddleURL(url) {
  let addr = new URL(url);
  let host = addr.host;
  let path = addr.pathname;

  // Check in hostname that tsfiddle exist or not
  let jsfiddleExist = host.includes("jsfiddle");

  if (jsfiddleExist) {


    //Check if jsfiddle URL has username(e.g /test/)
    let pathsContent = path.split("/").filter(
      el => {
        return el != ""
      }
    );
    // pathscontent will atleast have two items in it       
    if (pathsContent.length >= 2) {
      let newURL = `${host}${path}`;

      //Remove www. from the newURL if present
      newURL = newURL.replace("www.", '');

      //Check if the last character of the newURL has forward-slash(/) or not
      let newURLlen = newURL.length;
      let charOfNewURL = newURL.charAt(newURLlen - 1)

      if (charOfNewURL === "/")
        newURL = newURL.slice(0, -1)

      console.log(`Desired Result : ${newURL}`)

    } else {
      console.log("user name (eg: test) missing....... ")
    }

  } else {
    console.log("jsfiddle missing....... ")
  }
}

validateJsfiddleURL("https://www.jsfiddle.net/test/wLrk94mp/");

validateJsfiddleURL("http://www.jsfiddle.net/test/wLrk94mp/");


validateJsfiddleURL("https://www.jsfiddle.net/wLrk94mp/");
validateJsfiddleURL("http://www.ssfiddle.net/wLrk94mp/");
```

Comment: Thanks, would this also validate if the URL is correct

Comment: @methuselah Can you explain what do you exactly mean by a valid URL. Please provide some examples.

Comment: The URL in the format `jsfiddle.net/test/wLrk94mp` is in the correct format, but not `jsfiddle.net/wLrk94mp` for instance, or a `tsfiddle.net/test/wLrk94mp`

Comment: So what I understood that you need ``jsfiddle`` spelling correct, and also the  ``/test/`` or similarly username kind of thing.

Comment: Yep! That's all it is

Comment: @methuselah update my answer, you  can use ``includes()`` to check if **jsfiddle** word exists or not

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method, this time using .split and .filter

```js
console.log(
  `https://jsfiddle.net/test/wLrk94mp?hello=there#hellothere`.split('/').filter(a => a && !['http:', 'https:'].includes(a)).join('/').split(/[#?]/g)[0]
);
```